# It keeps updating all of the rows as the samething

Tags: php

```
<?php

$method = strtoupper($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]);
if($method === "POST") {

        $edittask = [
            "TName"=>$_POST["TName"],
            "description"=>$_POST["description"],
            "status"=>$_POST["status"],
            "duedate"=>$_POST["duedate"],
            "userassign"=>$_POST["userassign"],
        ];
        // use prepared statement to protect against SQL Injection
        $sql ="UPDATE task_list SET task_name=:TName,description=:description,status=:status,due_date=:duedate,user_assign=:userassign WHERE id=:uid";
        $statement = $DB->prepare($sql);
        try { 
             // execute statement
            $statement->execute($edittask);
            header("location: /task/tasks");
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: I honestly don't see how that code can update any rows at all instead of erroring out since you have defined 6 placeholders but only pass in 5 values (missing `uid`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the parameters(bind) to the query object.
Please see the bindParam method.

```
$sql ="UPDATE task_list SET task_name=:TName,description=:description,status=:status,due_date=:duedate,user_assign=:userassign WHERE id=:uid";
$statement = $DB->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindParam(':uid',$userId);
```

[BindParam Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)